# C++ if(Array[x].length > 0)

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to make a simple database program that gives users the ability to add, remove, and edit string variables.

**The issue I ran into: Assigning each added variable to the next empty array element.**

-I'm using static arrays for now until I learn more about dynamic arrays.

-Since this is out of context I recreated the code here to make more sense, sorry if I missed anything.

```
//static array declaration
std::string names[5];

//string selection from main function
std::string stringSel = "Item";

//boolean condition for loop
bool completed = false;

//if (names[x].length > 0) then increment x by 1 until names[x].length == 0 and then set that array element to the value from stringSel
int x = 0
while(completed == false)
{
    //if the length of the element is greater than zero characters, increment the element
    if (names[x].length > 0)
    {
        x++;
    }
    //if the length of the element is not greater than zero characters, set the string to that element
    else
    {
        //The empty element is assigned the string and the entire array prints out
        names[x] = stringSel;
        std::cout << stringSel << " was added to the database.\nThis is the printout of all current items: " << names;
        completed = true;
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is coming from my if-statements condition. The '.' is underlined red

**1 IntelliSense: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
names[x].length
```

[`std::string::length()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) is a member function, not a data member, so to access it you need to make a function call like:

```
names[x].length()
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved that easily and makes sense. So is std the class, string the object, and length the member? I just recently learned how classes and objects work.

Comment: @Bijan Kelley You are welcome. `std` is the namespace that the `string` class belong to and `length()` is a member function of the `string` class. The object of the `string` class in this case is what `names[x]` holds since you creates the array like `std::string names[5];`.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up too! Just learned about namespaces in the past week as well, so it seems we killed two birds with one stone just now.

Comment: @BijanKelley Yes, it seem like that! :) Good luck!